# C# - Should Streams always be Closed, even if they didn't open properly?

Tags: c#, stream, visual-studio-2013, dispose

If i make a Stream object to open a text file with `OpenFileDialog`, in what scope should i close it? In the same scope were i declared it, or inside one of the `if`s (to close it just in the case that it opened properly)?.

I leave you the code here so you can tell me...

```
Stream arch_Usuarios;

OpenFileDialog openFileDialog_arch_Usuarios = new OpenFileDialog();

if (openFileDialog_arch_Usuarios.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    if ((arch_Usuarios = openFileDialog_arch_Usuarios.OpenFile()) != null)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Greetings.

Comment: Look into `using` statement. That should solve this problem.

Comment: What do you meant by "they didn't open properly" ?

Comment: If a stream doesn't open properly, you won't get `null` or an uninitialized stream, but an exception.

Comment: Side note: Use .net naming conversions. refrain using `Abc_Def` style

Answer (score 6):

If you put those resources in a `using` statement, you won't have to worry about it.  These objects are automatically cleaned up when they go out of scope, regardless of how the code exits, meaning even in the event that exception is thrown.

```
using(OpenFileDialog openFileDialog_arch_Usuarios = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    if (openFileDialog_arch_Usuarios.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        using(Stream arch_Usuarios = openFileDialog_arch_Usuarios.OpenFile())
        {
            ...
        }        
    }
}
```

And here's my one pet peeve with `using` statements.  You wind up with ridiculously indented code.  Minor complaint, but still annoys me.

Comment: You need to use `OpenFileDialog` in using statement as well

Comment: True.  They could all go in using statements.  The one thing I don't like about using statements (and this is minor) is the indentation that results.  I tend to use them sparingly for that reason.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: I don't think the dialog needs to go in a `using`, only the stream

Comment: @musefan Why? `OpenFileDialog` uses unmanaged system resource, which has to be disposed.

Comment: It could be argued either way.  For readability, I prefer to use them sparingly.  @musefan, the file dialog will be disposed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Hmmmm, yes, after some quick reading it appears it should be disposed

Comment: @TimCoker: If it contains unmanaged resources, like SriramSakthivel suggests, then they will not be automatically cleaned up when out of scope, so they need manually disposing (or with `using`)